# Set window title to arbitrary sequence of characters in the st terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

I would like to set up a ZSH hook to set the terminal window title to contain information such as the previously entered command and the PWD. The naïve window title-setting shell function would look like this:

```
title() { printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$*" }
```

But, in basic usage, this proves to be completely inadequate. It is very easy to interrupt the ANSI escape sequence with various special characters, such as `;`.
I have tried explicitly substituting `;` with `\;` which does not work. How can I escape arbitrary sequences of characters so that a valid escape sequence can be generated to set the window title correctly?

EDIT: This problem actually seems to be a quirk of `st`. I will post the solution I figured out below.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? `;` is fine for me with `xterm`, `screen`, `gnome-terminal`, `Eterm` and `rxvt` here.

Comment: I am using ``st``.

Answer (score 1):

`st` interprets the `;` as delimiting another argument in the escape sequence. `st` sets the window title to the contents of the first argument only. To fix this, I have replaced the code handling the specific escape sequence from this:

```
if (narg > 1)
    xsettitle(strescseq.args[1]);
```

To this:

```
if (narg > 1) {
    char *buf = malloc(1);
    buf[0] = '\0';
    int n = 0;
    for (int i=1;i<narg;i++) {
        buf = realloc(buf, n+=(strlen(strescseq.args[i]) + 1));
        strcat(buf, strescseq.args[i]);
        if (i + 1 != narg)
            strcat(buf, ";");
    }
    xsettitle(buf);
    free(buf);
}
```

This may or may not be a good solution.